# Python.exe is 0KB on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7-x64

I'm using Windows 7 64 bit and I have installed **Python 2.7**. After some other installations I have discovered that the python.exe in *C:\Python27\* is actually **0KB**, so I wanted to reinstall Python but I encounter an error.

I tried to uninstall python both from *Programs and features* and also from a Python **.msi** installer. Both ways the following error occurs:

[image]

I don't find registry values for python and I have removed the system variable for Python and there is no path to Python in the **PATH** system variable.

What may be causing this problem?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I just deleted the whole folder **C:\Python27** but the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

These are the things that I did:

1. Since I had two users on my PC(one of which is no longer used), and I had installed Python 2.7 on the other user I entered C:\Users and deleted the folder of the other User
2. I deleted the content of C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp
3. I started searching for registries in regedit and started deleting all registries that I found related to Python. After deleting at least 10 registries I decided to stop and give the uninstall another try and it worked.

I don't know if this solution helps others, but It solved the problem in my case. As a whole, the problem was that somewhere something was using python in the background and the uninstall component could not remove it from my PC.

Answer (score 1):

- In explorer go to `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp`
- Right-click properties of `Temp'
- Click the Security tab
- Click Edit
- Click Add under the groups and usernames
- Type `Everyone` in the text box, and hit OK
- Then in the bottom text box in the Allow column tick FULL CONTROL
- Apply the changed settings

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I managed to solve the problem and posted an answer, you can check it out. Your answer could have given a hint to me.